# Count permutations with LCM

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, divisibility

Given $N,M$ and $D$ we need to count how many permutations of $N$ integers are there with each $i$'th element $1 \le A[i] \le M$ such that least common multiple (LCM) of all its elements is divisible by number $D$.

Here $M$ is at max $1000$ and $N$ can go up to $10^6$.

How to approach this question? Please help as i can't even think of how to start it.So some ideas will be very helpful to tackle this problem.

Can their be direct formula for this question ? Assuming I am have prime factorisation of $D$.

Comment: I think "permutations" (which means arrangements) of integers is not what you mean here (since LCM doesn't change with rearrangement), but rather "combinations" of the $M$ integers from $1$ to $M$ taken $N$ at a time.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah..But in question 1 2 is different from 2 1

Comment: Is this a contest question?

Comment: @hardmath Not any contest problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a question from an on-going contest and the OP lied about it.

Answer (score 1):

A hint to get you started:  If you factor $D$, at least one of the $A$'s has to account for each of the prime powers that divide $D$.  So for $D=600=2^3\cdot3\cdot 5^2$, at least one of the $A$'s must be divisible by $2^3$, at least one (maybe the same one) must be divisible by $3$, and one must be divisible by $5^2$  If you imagine a three circle Venn diagram, each region represents one class of factors.  One class will have a factor $2^3$ and $3$ but not $5^2$ for example.  Figure out how many numbers are in each class.  If $A[1]$ is from that class, you only need a factor of $5^2$ from one of the rest.  You can use dynamic programming, calling with $N-1$ and the remaining $D$

Added:  here is a small example.  Let $N=4, D=6, M=12$.  As $6=2\cdot 3$ the divisibility classes are $1,2,3,6$.  Class $6$ includes $6,12$.  Class $3$ includes $3,9$.  If $A[1]$ is from class $6$, the rest can be anything, so this contributes $2 \cdot 12^3$ possibilities.  If $A[1]$ is from class $3$, at least one of the rest has to be even, so this contributes $2$ times the solution with $N=3,D=2,M=12$

Comment: Can you please explain how to use dynammic programming here?And why M-1 ?

Comment: You are just calling your own program after you have picked $A[1]$.  The new problem now allows one less number in the set, hence the $M-1$, but $D$ is smaller by whatever factors $A[1]$ has already provided.  You loop over the classes that $A[1]$ can belong to.

Comment: Can you please provide some example or pseudocode for it ?

Comment: I understand all part except Dynammic programming one

Comment: Also please explain "Figure out how many numbers are in each class." ?How to count this ?

Comment: Inclusion/exclusion might be a more easily understood framework.  Take all N-tuples with M-bounded entries, subtract for each maximal prime power factor $q|D$ those N-tuples that avoid multiples of $q$, add back for each pair of prime power factors those that avoid multiples of their product, etc.

Comment: In my example, if $D=600$ the classes are multiples of $1,8,3,25,24,200,75,600$ where the $75$ class does not include multiples of $600$.  Do you see what is going on here?  Now see how many numbers up to $M$  are in each of these

Comment: @hardmath Can you explain with some suitable example ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Like here say M=1000 then in each class other than 75  we have 1000/1,1000/8,1000/3 and so on ..Right ?Also how are we making classes ?

Comment: Close.  In class $600$ there is only one-$600$.  In class $200$ there would be $5$ but we already put $600$ in a separate class, so there are only $4$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok.and why are not considering 75? I mean criteria for making classes

Comment: We are considering $75$.  There would be $\lfloor 1000/75 \rfloor=13$ in that class, but one of them is $600$, so there are $12$ left.  Then the idea is that if $A[1]$ is one of these, the rest of the numbers just have to supply the factor $8$, so one of them comes from one of the classes that is a multiple of $8$, and the rest can be anything.  If $A[1]$ comes from a different class, you need some other set of factors from the rest of the list.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why you had written  "where the 75 class does not include multiples of 600"?

Comment: @RossMillikan Please explain this example in your answer explanation please.It will remove all doubts

Comment: The point is more general.  No class includes multiples of any higher class.  You count 1 multiple of 600, then there are 12 multiples of 75 left, 4 multiples of 200 left, and 41 multiples of 24 left.  Now there would be 125 multiples of 8, but we have already assigned 1+4+41=46 of them to higher classes, so there are 79 in that class.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok .what after we had calculated multiples count in each class like here we have 79,24,4 etc

Comment: Then you have eight possibilities for the class A[1] comes from.  If it comes from class 8, you know there are 79 ways for that to happen.  Now you need to select $N-1$ more numbers that will give you a multiplier of $75$.  Call your program with $D=75$ and $N$ reduced by $1$  When it returns, multiply its result by $79$ and you have the number of ways to succeed if A[1] is from that class.  Repeat for the other seven classes and add the results.

Comment: @RossMillikan By 8 possibilities you mean [1,8,3,25,24,200,75,600] ? Now if A[1] come from class 8 then A[2] come from remaining classes or only class 75  .Just explain last line Repeat for the other seven classes and add the results.

Comment: Yes, those are the eight possibilities.  If A[1] comes from class 8, you ignore factors of 8 in the rest, so now there are four classes, 1,3,25,75.  The rest of the numbers need to combine to have a factor 3 and a factor 25.  That could come from one number from each class or a single number from class 75.  You are trying to compute the number of ways to satisfy this with N-1 numbers. So one case is A[2] is from class 3,and you get a 25 from somewhere later.  Another is A[2] is from class 1 and you still need both factors later.

Comment: Please avoid extensive discussion in comments.